# Pushing response from Server into Client in android?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-manifest, android-2.2-froyo

i am developing an restaurant menu app in android for Samsung galaxy tab. On my app user will select the food item and user will place an order. The list of items to be served is dispatched to the server through SOAP service. Now as soon as the the order get placed from the kitchen i want to notify the user that an order has been dispatched.
What i got while searching is that i can use **PUSH Technology** i.e. **C2DM Cloud to Device Messanging**. But i had not got proper code to use this in my app. Can any one give me a proper **implementation of C2DM in android**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many push technologies.  Another option is to use XMPP, as it will work on Android.

You can check [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) and [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) for XMPP.  The asmack project is an Android specific derivitive of Smack, although there are people using Smack directly as well.

Comment: can you provide any link where actual implementation of XMPP or C2DM will be there. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @PCS - Updated my answer with some more info.